# Is Source Code of Google Code Open Source

Tags: open-source, repository

We in our company are looking to setup a code repository to which multiple groups can contribute. I am looking for a system like Google Code with following features:

i. Wiki

ii. Issue Tracker

iii. Source Repository (SVN integration)

iv. Control the access to make modifications to the code

The closest open source alternative I could find is "Trac".

1) Is the code of Google Code Open Source? A google search does not take me to any useful link.

2) Any suggestions for open source software matching the above needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This from the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ):

> **Is Google Code's implementation itself open source?**
>
> As with most project-hosting sites,
>   our underlying technology is a mixture
>   of open source and proprietary code.
>   For example, the issue tracker is
>   entirely written by Google, but the
>   version-control service is based on
>   Subversion, a popular open source
>   tool.

We use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) & [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) here at work, though I'm sure there are other options available.

Comment: Thanks for the FAQ snippet. I think we will go ahead with Trac, SVN. Can I restrict user access in SVN?

Comment: I meant a user role access using Trac for SVN

Comment: You can set up Permission Groups in Trac and restrict what users in those groups can do: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions#PermissionGroups (I think that's what you're asking?) You can also set up quite complex permissions within SVN - though I'm no expert on that side of things.

Comment: Trac has a great integration with Subversion. Give it a try.

Comment: That solves most of the requirements. Will go with Trac+SVN.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently started using GitHub for scm and I have to say it's pretty damn nice.

https://github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Choosing one solution that has all 4 of those requirements might be the wrong approach - I've found its better to choose the best tool for the job, and not use a 12-in-1 tool like a Swiss Army Knife.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) is one of the better source control solutions, and there are a variety of bug tracker and documentation tools to choose from.  I personally use [CodeTrack](http://kennwhite.sourceforge.net/codetrack/) as a bug tracker - it's extremely simple and does not require a database connection, although I know CodeTrack is not one of the more popular ones out there.